# How to pass Delegated property anonymously in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, delegates, parameter-passing, lazy-evaluation, delegated-properties

Let's assume a simple class:

```
class Foo(val p:String)
```

I would like to create instance of the class by passing **lazy delegate**:

```
val lazyP by lazy {"foo"}
println(Foo(lazyP).p)
```

but I don't need the boilerplate `lazyP` variable. How to write a one-liner? Something like:

```
println(Foo(by lazy {"foo"}).p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume what you're trying to do is construct `Foo` and have `p` only calculated when it's first called? If so, I don't think that defining `Foo` as you've done will work, because when you construct `Foo`, the lazy delegate is called. That's because in order to construct `Foo`, a string is needed, so the lazy delegate is evaluated at that point. In other words, this:

```
val lazyP by lazy { "foo" }
val foo = Foo(lazyP)
```

is more-or-less equivalent to:

```
val foo = Foo("foo")
```

I think that if you want `Foo` to have a lazy delegated property you should define it like this:

```
class Foo(lazyP: Lazy<String>) {
    val p by lazyP
}
```

Then you can construct it in a one-liner without needing a separate variable:

```
val foo = Foo(lazy { "foo" })
```

Comment: Ok, thats neat. But how can I make this lazy if I can't change the `Foo` class?

Comment: Good question :-) Are you able to change the client of `Foo` so that it doesn't use `Foo` directly, and instead uses some class you write which wraps or subclasses `Foo`?

Comment: Well, in this case, yes. But I imagine that wrapper isn't the cleanest solution. I wish the Kotlin compiler would generate inline lambda in places where `val p` is used.